# Regex Redirection with numbers

Tags: regex, redirect

I wish to redirect a link from

```
http:www.testurl.com/1209/somecategory/itemid
```

to

```
http:www.testurl.com/en/uk/1209/somecategory/itemid
```

by using a regex expression.

At the moment I have come up with

```
<redirect url="~/\d/(.*)$" to="~/en/uk/0/$1/" />
```

which works when the number is 0.

How can I get the number entered (/d) to the second part of the link (instead of the 0)?

Thanks for your help and time

Comment: Try using `url="~/(\d+/.*)$"`. And replace with `to="~/en/uk/$1/"`.

Comment: Yes that works!  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the `\d+` (1 or more digits) to the capturing group:

```
url="~/(\d+/.*)$"
```

And replace using the `$1` back-reference:

```
to="~/en/uk/$1/"
```

Thus, you do not have to hard-code digits into the replacement string.

See [*Use Parentheses for Grouping and Capturing*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) and [*Numbered Backreferences*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html) for more details on how capturing can be used in regex.

**See [Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pF4qA8/2)**